# NVIDIA X Server Settings not executing

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics, xserver

I'm facing an issue in Ubuntu 16.04 with ***NVIDIA X Server Settings*** application each time I try to execute it, it closes systematically.

Comment: The issue is that **NVIDIA X Server** do not opens when I switch to Intel Graphic card using `sudo prime-select intel` but opens normally in NVIDIA Graphic card `sudo prime-select NVIDIA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By switching to NVIDIA `sudo prime-select nvidia` **NVIDIA X Server** opens without any problem

Comment: works great just a restart is needed!